# Interaction of sidebar and frametitle

Tags: beamer

This source files (note that `\useoutertheme{sidebar}` is commented)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% \useoutertheme{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=orange}
\begin{document}
\section{Outline}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

but if I uncomment `\useoutertheme{sidebar}` I have two differences in the titlebar, the fg text color and  its height.

[image]

I'm particularly disturbed by the large increase in the titlebar height, is it possible to revert the changes that using the sidebar entails?

Comment: Well, it looks different, because you are using **a different theme**.

Answer (score 2):

the `sidebar` theme reserves an amount of vertical space for a possible logo and/or to avoid *wobbling* of the titleframe height; the height of this vertical space is configurable, e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[height=25pt]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=orange}
\begin{document}
\section{Outline}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]